# Speech recognition printing transcripts

Tags: python, python-3.x

So my speech recognition in python is printing transcripts and its annoying. Here's how it looks like

> Listening..
> Recognizing..
> result2:
> {   'alternative': [{'confidence': 0.88687539, 'transcript': 'Hello Spartan'}],
> 'final': True}
> You said: Hello Spartan

Here's my listening code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr

def listen():

    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listening..")
        r.pause_threshold = 1
        audio = r.listen(source,0,5)

    try:
        print("Recognizing..")
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-in', show_all=False)
        print(f'You said: {query}') 
    
    except:
        return ""

    query = str(query)
    return query.lower()
```

Any way to fix this?

Comment: try deleting show_all=False

Comment: you already have `show_all=False`, so the additional possible transcriptions should _not_ be showing.

Comment: i tried deleting them and adding them back, even changing their value to True, still no luck.

Comment: Ok, looking at the source code for this function at https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/010382b80267f0f7794169fccc8e875ee7da7c19/speech_recognition/__init__.py#L855, it is returning the entire JSON API response in `query`. There is another parameter, `with_confidence` which is `False` by default, what happens if you explicitly set that to `False` in the parameters? Another easy way around this is to use ` print(f'You said: {query.transcript}')` instead - this just shows the `transcript` part of the API response.

Comment: i'll check and update you all on this. thank you all for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a bug in the code. I've solved this by downgrading the speech_recognition library:

```
pip install SpeechRecognition==3.8.1
```

Comment: ok thank you so much LegoJesus. This really helped.